# What is wrong with my "disproof" of Cantor's Theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, fake-proofs

I cannot figure out what is wrong:

We will attempt to show that $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ is countable. We use the following corollary from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, p. 29:

> Suppose $A$ is at most countable, and, for every $\alpha\in A$, $B_{\alpha}$ is at most countable. Put
>
> $$T=\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_{\alpha}$$
>
> Then $T$ is at most countable.

*"Proof" 1:*

Let $A = \mathbb{N}$ and for every $\alpha \in A$ let $B_{\alpha}=\{S \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})| \text{the sum of the elements of } S \text{ is } \alpha \}$. $A$ is countable and for every $\alpha \in A$, $B_{\alpha}$ is finite. Therefore

$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_{\alpha}$$

is countable. But $\displaystyle \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_{\alpha}=\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$, so $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ is countable.

---

*"Proof" 2:*

Let $A= \mathbb{N}$ and for every $\alpha \in A$ let $B_{\alpha}=\{ S \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}): |S| = \alpha \}$. I think that I can show by induction (if requested) that for each $\alpha \in A$, $B_{\alpha}$ is countable. Thus

$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_{\alpha}$$

is countable. But again, $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_{\alpha} = \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$

Comment: In both cases, the union of the $B_{\alpha}$ is the set of *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (which is indeed countable, and this is indeed a correct proof of that fact).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah ok thank you

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain?

Comment: Well at least you acknowledge you have a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am tired of the billion questions all involving the same misunderstanding of Cantor, and further many posters (not all) cannot be reasoned with. So I downvote all such questions. Maybe you should read some of the other answers.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Nobody can dictate to you how to use your votes, but the Help Center says "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I don't think my question falls into any of those categories. Additionally, I don't think my question is a duplicate and I fail to find another where the poster had the same misunderstanding (just an oversight rather) as me.

Comment: Ovi, don't worry. It's a good question. It's asked correctly per MSE rules, and it shows a frequent mistake, so it's likely to help other readers passing by. I just suspect it's a duplicate, because it's really a counterargument that is easy to imagine.

Comment: Rene Schipperus.  You are right.  How dare anybody who doesn't understand mathematics ask a question about mathematics on a mathematics help site.  I'm tired of people not as perfect as I am wasting mine but not their own time in the pointless purpose of attempting to learn something they don't understand.

Comment: If there are indeed a number of questions all asking about the same or a similar issue in "disproving" Cantor, it is definitely a sign of not checking the prior questions and a poor effort to ask about it again. I have certainly downvoted such questions before (repeats a common question with many instances already present), and it seems Rene has done so here.

Comment: @Nij I agree. However, I've checked around before asking the question and I wasn't able to find anything dealing with my specific question. Rene has not provided a duplicate either.

Comment: You're not a fresh user. You do know that there is an uncountable number of proofs of this vein already on the site, each with a handful of disproofs. Some more specific (e.g. "this set is a counterexample") and others less specific (e.g. "your suggestion fails for infinite sets because..."). Is it so hard to search before posting?

Comment: Upvote for having to deal with jerks

Comment: @Ben Another upvote from me, same reason.

Comment: @Ben: I didn't downvote, but how about a downvote for people who don't bother searching the site? (Because honestly, *all* the arguments regarding Cantor's theorem have been covered ad nauseum...) or is it considered bad manners to point out that someone disregards the immense efforts by so many users to provide an answer to this question before? I don't know, but it seems to me that "jerk" can apply to everyone involved in this conversation (including me, being a jerk for pointing this out).

Comment: Just on the matter of style - why should we let $A=\mathbb N$? We already have a very nice symbol for $\mathbb N$, namely $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @JackM Probably because the theorem which is being used has a set named $A$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "You do know that there is an uncountable number of proofs of this vein already **on the site** [emphasis added], each with a handful of disproofs. "  I hope that was a joke, because the number of proofs and disproofs on this site is countable.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In both your "proofs", it is not true that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_{\alpha}=\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$.  Indeed, if $S\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is any infinite set, then $S$ is not in any $B_\alpha$ (by either definition).

What both your arguments show correctly is that the set of all *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: Ah got it thanks!

Comment: @Ovi: Furthermore, this fact is important, because similarly the set of all finite sequences of naturals is countable, such as when counting the number of integer polynomials.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, then we have shown that the set of algebraic numbers is countable.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Right. And similarly that there are countably many computable reals, and also countably many definable reals regardless of how powerful one's foundational system is.

Comment: @user21820 It is consistent that all reals are definable, so it is not provable that there are only countably many definable reals. See this MathOverflow answer:
https://mathoverflow.net/q/44129
(The other statements are correct.)

Comment: @RobertFurber: Within ZFC we can construct the standard reals and can prove that they are uncountable. We can also prove that there are only countably many formulae over ZFC that define a set, and hence only countably many of the standard reals can be defined by one of these formulae. Hence what you stated is imprecise if not wrong. Even if you know what you are talking about, I think you shouldn't confuse beginner students with esoteric set theoretic issues that are unrelated to the basic facts about countability.

Comment: @user21820 Re-read the 4th & 5th paragraphs of [Joel Hamkins' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44129) to see why that argument fails. It was _you_ who put "esoteric set theoretic issues" in front of beginning students in the first place by introducing definability. You then compounded this error by expounding a common fallacy about it.

Comment: @RobertFurber: I know there are common pitfalls. But there are no esoteric set-theoretic issues unlike what **you** think. Whichever foundational system S you choose, as long as S is nice enough and has a collection of reals, then within S you **can** ask the question of whether a real satisfies some property over S in all models M of S with the same reals. It may be that there are no models of S with the same reals, but you should not believe that otherwise S is clearly defective. We should not be able to prove that such a model exists, but if it does then there are countably many such reals.

Comment: @RobertFurber: Bringing up models of **set theory** is irrelevant, since definability of reals can be handled in the way I have specified for **any** reasonable foundational system. If there is any error, point it out. But if not, please take back your accusation of me being fallacious. Thanks.

Comment: @user21820 I cannot fathom why you have not simply read Joel Hamkins' answer. Also, until you goaded me into it, I have not uttered the word "model".

i) If the argument you suggest succeded, there would be countably many definable ordinals. There would therefore be a smallest undefinable ordinal. But this is, itself, a definition of that ordinal, a contradiction (a variant of Berry's paradox).

ii) Tarski's undefinability theorem means that the mapping from formulas to the reals that they define is not itself definable.
This is all adequately explained in Joel Hamkins' answer.

Comment: @user21820 If you want to understand how this relates to models, I suggest you familiarize yourself with Skolem's paradox. This will be my last statement on the matter.

Comment: @RobertFurber: I cannot fathom why you simply refuse to read my comment properly. Which part of "We should **not** be able to prove that such a model exists, but **if it does then** there are countably many such reals." do you fail to understand? Indeed, as you stated, there is no reason for you to say anymore on the matter. For future readers: Robert is wrong about (i), because my argument cannot be used to prove the existence of a set of definable ordinals. Robert is also wrong about (ii), for similar reason.

Comment: @user21820 I think Robert is mostly in the right here. Although the statement "There is an undefinable real" is not actually expressible in the language of set theory the existence of models of ZFC in which every real is definable means (to me) that ZFC "morally" doesn't prove that there are undefinable reals. Of course, ZFC *does* prove "If $M$ is a model of ZFC with uncountably many reals, then there is some real in $M$ which is not definable in $M$," but that's quite different. (Of course I agree with you that this is well beyond the scope of the OP, but it is a real issue with your claim.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Once anyone defines "definable" in any reasonable sense, my original statement would be true. You also cannot say that Robert is mostly in the right when I have fully explained my statement whereas he merely says I am wrong. Finally, note that I said "Bringing up models of set theory is irrelevant, since definability of reals can be handled in the way I have specified for any reasonable foundational system." To state that set-theoretic issues are crucial to the issue of "definable reals" is misleading to readers unless set theory is the only valid foundation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I would like to emphasize that Robert also said my argument would give nonsensical results **after** I had explained it fully. So it is clear enough that he is wrong about (i) and (ii), regardless of how he interpreted my original statements.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Finally, off-topic, but I think your 'moral' reasoning is not applicable to the particular way I stated my claim; notice I purposely said "with the same reals". Suppose you believe ZFC is **meaningful**. Then you construct in ZFC a model R of the real axioms, and prove that R is **unique** up to isomorphism, so you ought to **believe** that there is a model of ZFC within which there is a structure isomorphic to R, otherwise why should you believe ZFC is meaningful when it does not have a model that 'agrees with itself about what R is'? =)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're getting at, to be honest. ZFC proves "Every model of ZFC containing every real (call this "R-standard") contains an undefinable real. However, this doesn't do what I think you want it to do. First of all, it could be vacuous - in any model of ZFC which thinks ZFC is inconsistent. More seriously, even if M is a model of ZFC containing lots of R-standard models of ZFC, what is undefinable in one R-standard model in M may not be undefinable in another. In particular, there's no tension between this and every real being definable in M itself.

Comment: Beyond that, while it's certainly quite weird I don't see any incoherence in the position that every real number is definable: I think one can be a Platonist, believe that the ZFC axioms are true, and *still* believe that every real number is definable in the set-theoretic universe - this would entail believing that no map sending a real to a formula defining it is actually a set, but I don't see any immediate philosophical problems with that. (There's a limited spiritual similarity in my mind between this and the "potential countability" of every set under the multiverse approach.)

Comment: (The second-to-last sentence of my first comment today is in response to your statement "Whichever foundational system S you choose, as long as S is nice enough and has a collection of reals, then within S you can ask the question of whether a real satisfies some property over S in all models M of S with the same reals.") So I have to say I'm with Robert on this one.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I don't know why I didn't reply to your message. If you don't mind, I would like to continue our discussion, whether here or in [the logic room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic). My view is basically the last sentence [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/5432507). I felt that if one believes that ZFC is meaningful then one should believe in a **set** model of ZFC with the same reals, because the reals are essentially unique.

Comment: To put it another way, suppose you believe ZFC is meaningful, and work within ZFC as your foundational system. Then every R-standard model has undefinable reals, as you agreed. Now if ZFC is truly foundational, what it proves about every model of ZFC should also reflect the universe within which you are working in (the intended model of your foundational system), even though you can't prove it. By definition of R-standard (it has the same reals as your universe), this includes the property that every R-standard model has undefinable reals. It can't be proven, but why wouldn't you believe it?

Comment: @user21820 *My* return to apologize for the late reply! The point I (potentially, depending on how I'm feeling) take issue with is your claim "Now if ZFC is truly foundational, what it proves about every [R-standard] model of ZFC should also reflect the universe within which you are working in." I don't think that's necessarily true. In particular, we can add to our usual list of "things sets should be" that *every set is "definable" in some sense* - this isn't too weird, since it matches up with the idea that mathematics is a creation of the human mind. (cont'd)

Comment: The tension here is then resolved by the claim that in the true universe of sets, we have a kind of "emergent definability" - the mathematical objects which actually exist are rather conservative, and although some limited amount of information might make it look as if we have some "wildness" (= undefinability), once the entire picture is given to us this conservativity appears. Personally I find this very attractive from time to time. "Minimality" hypotheses like this tend to be viewed as unattractive in my experience, but I don't quite buy that myself, at least not all the time.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Hmm but your viewpoint does not seem to address my objection. If ZFC is truly a correct picture of the universe U (otherwise it does not make sense to claim ZFC to be foundational), then you have to believe that ZFC has a model. Also, since ZFC tells us that the the reals R are essentially unique, you have to believe that ZFC has a model with an isomorphic copy of R. Furthermore, there should be one such model M that reflects U, otherwise ZFC is not a correct picture of U since it cannot see a model that reflects U! M clearly has undefinable reals, and is supposed to reflect U.

Comment: @user21820 "Furthermore, there should be one such model M that reflects U, otherwise ZFC is not a correct picture of U since it cannot see a model that reflects U!"  I don't buy that at all. Quite reasonably in my opinion, one may believe that any set model of ZFC only *partially* reflects the true universe U. Just because all set models have some property doesn't mean that U has that property too - e.g. every set model is "missing some set," but U certainly isn't!

Comment: @user21820 To avoid spamming Eric unnecessarily, let's continue this at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82604/pointwise-definable-models-discussion.